# How do I set an exchange header to the result of a route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route which has a step which calls a subroute to convert the text portion of the body to PDF. Unfortunately `camel-pdf` does not preserve headers. Is there a way I can get the value of the subroute without losing my current exchange?

**Sub Route**

```
from("seda:generate-pdf")

// Back up the original in a header
.setHeader("original", body())

// Create the PDF
.to("pdf:create?textProcessingFactory=autoFormatting")
// UHOH! All my headers are gone :(

// Set the PDF as the header for the doc server
.setHeader("pdf", body())

// Move the indicator back to the body
.setBody(header("original")) // <-- this no longer exists
```

**Main Route**

```
// Snip

// Unmarshal into Java

.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, MyReportContainingText.class)

// Call sub-route to generate the PDF
.inOut("seda:generate-pdf")
// UHOH! All my headers are gone :(

// Snip
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of saving stuff in the headers which can be removed when you pass from one route to another save them as exchange properties. For example:

```
.setProperty("pdf", body())
.setProperty("pdf", simple("${body}")
```

Exchange property exist as long as the exchange exist.

Comment: doesn't help for me

Comment: @gstackoverflow, you need to explain more.